# Read Json with features fields

Tags: php, json

I have the following problem.
I am trying to read a Json file but I am not getting the desired result. I have the following data.

I would like to read the features and there is a mistake in finding out somewhere.

I get the error message when reading out:
Warning:  Illegal string offset 'features'

Output

```
Array
(
    [objectIdFieldName] => OBJECTID
    [uniqueIdField] => Array
        (
            [name] => OBJECTID
            [isSystemMaintained] => 1
        )

    [globalIdFieldName] => 
    [geometryProperties] => Array
        (
            [shapeAreaFieldName] => Shape__Area
            [shapeLengthFieldName] => Shape__Length
            [units] => esriMeters
        )

    [geometryType] => esriGeometryPolygon
    [spatialReference] => Array
        (
            [wkid] => 4326
            [latestWkid] => 4326
        )

    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => GEN
                    [type] => esriFieldTypeString
                    [alias] => GEN
                    [sqlType] => sqlTypeOther
                    [length] => 33
                    [domain] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cases
                    [type] => esriFieldTypeInteger
                    [alias] => Anzahl Fälle
                    [sqlType] => sqlTypeOther
                    [domain] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => deaths
                    [type] => esriFieldTypeInteger
                    [alias] => Anzahl Todesfälle
                    [sqlType] => sqlTypeOther
                    [domain] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                )

        )

    [features] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [GEN] => Celle
                            [cases] => 220
                            [deaths] => 15
                        )

                    ...........
```

My Code

```
$url = "https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_Landkreisdaten/FeatureServer/0/query?where=GEN%20%3D%20%27CELLE%27&outFields=GEN,cases,deaths&outSR=4326&f=json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json,true); //decode json result as array and thenloop it
print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
foreach($data as $row){
echo $row['features']->$row['attributes']->$row['GEN'];
}
```

Where am I wrong in reading?
It only has to be read what is in parentheses right?

So actually features-> attributes-> Gen to get the GEN query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is my fault when seem does'nt read clearly your question.

With GEN attribute you don't use loop to get this value.

If you wanna get GEN only your code should be that.

```
$url = "https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_Landkreisdaten/FeatureServer/0/query?where=GEN%20%3D%20%27CELLE%27&outFields=GEN,cases,deaths&outSR=4326&f=json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = (array) json_decode($json, true); //decode json result as array and thenloop it
print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo $data['features']['attributes']['GEN'];

// foreach($data as $row){
// echo $row['features']->$row['attributes']->$row['GEN'];
// }
```

Comment: Ah my mistake is gone with the loop and just put it in an array. Thanks that helped me really well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try change to this.

```
foreach($data as $row){
   echo $row['features'][0]['attributes']['GEN'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have the same problem that all are now displayed as illegal string offset.

Illegal string offset 'features'
Illegal string offset 'GEN'
Illegal string offset 'attributes'

Comment: Let's check another answer because when Add Comment I don't know how to implement codes